# Android preference dialog styling

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme

I'm trying to unite dialogs in my application. All activities extend `AppCompatActivity`, so dialogs are material, except `DialogPreference` in my settings activity.

I was using `PreferenceActivity`, but I changed it to `AppCompatActivity` also, with use of `PreferenceFragment`. It made no difference.

So I tried to add custom style for my SettingsTheme like this

```
<style name="SettingsTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:dialogPreferenceStyle">@style/StyledDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="StyledDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
</style>
```

but everything I got is this (I also tried alertDialogStyle, alertDialogTheme and dialogTheme), holo dialog stays in place

[image]

Another thing I tried was to extend `EditTextPreference` and override `onPrepareDialogBuilder` with forcing my theme:

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(AlertDialog.Builder builder) {
    super.onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder);

    builder.getContext().setTheme(R.style.StyledDialog);
}
```

Also no success. Is there a way that dialogs in one application are AppCompat united and not every one of them different? I thought platform should solve that, but well, I forget I'm on Android.

**Edit:** After some digging I found that `DialogPreference` uses `android.app.AlertDialog` instead of `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`. So it looks like I have to find a way to override Builder in `DialogPreference`.

**Edit 2:** OK, so regarding the previous edit - I've been using non-support DialogPreference, so after adding `com.android.support:preference-v7:23.1.0` I had access to another classes set. But it looks like it's still buggy and little bit hacky, so I keep there those old dialogs and wait for support libraries update. Some interesting links I found are:

- [Preferences Support Library: Preference Fragments for API 7+, no matter the Activity](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/9kZ3SsXdT2T)
- [Android support preference @ GitHub](https://github.com/consp1racy/android-support-preference)
- [Android support preference v7 fix @ GitHub](https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix)

Comment: Have you tried it in any other phone?. This seams to be problem with your phone (Vendor).

Comment: I'm trying it on Galaxy nexus with Android 4.2.2 running MIUI - here are dialogs different, but on my Sony z3 with Android 5.1.1 is everything ok. I'm going to try it on emulator...

Comment: Emulator api 16 doesn't work either, so it's not problem just with one of my devices.

Comment: 1) dialogPreferenceStyle is for styling the preference widget not its dialog. 2) dialogStyle != dialogTheme 3) When asked for dialogTheme, supply ...Dialog theme. When asked for alertDialogTheme supply ...Dialog.Alert theme. **4) The second link should work from appcompat-v7 23.1.1 and do exactly what you need (hi, author here).**

Comment: did you find a solution for this? If yes please post